# Partial and semipartial correlation

Tags: fitting, coefficients, correlation

I am interested to know if there are built-in *Mathematica* functions that performs partial and semipartial computations.

If not, what would be a simple and efficient way to compute them from the results of a LinearModelFit?

Comment: The simplest way would be to use `RLink` and call the functions in the R package `ppcor`.  Alternatively using functions in *Mathematica* are pretty simple, too.  See the description of parial and semipartial correlation at http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Part3/Partials.html.

Comment: Thanks JimB. I am not quite sure that installing a second software and establishing links between the two is the _simplest_ way. However, it sure is a useful way to crossvalidate results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Mathematica* has a `PartialCorrelation` function but that is for time series data.  However by following the information in [Partial and semipartial correlation](http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Part3/Partials.html) you can use some simple *Mathematica* commands.

```
(* Data *)
SATV = {500, 550, 450, 400, 600, 650, 700, 550, 650, 550};
HSGPA = {3.0, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 3.2, 3.8, 3.9, 3.8, 3.5, 3.1};
FGPA = {2.8, 3.0, 2.8, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.5, 3.7, 3.4, 2.9};
data = Transpose[{SATV, HSGPA, FGPA}];

(* Find residuals for the two regressions on SATV *)
resid1 = LinearModelFit[data[[All, {1, 2}]], x, x]["FitResiduals"];
resid2 = LinearModelFit[data[[All, {1, 3}]], x, x]["FitResiduals"];

(* Partial correlation *)
Correlation[resid1, resid2]
(* 0.7475739092548284 *)

(* Semipartial correlation *)
Correlation[FGPA, resid1]
(* 0.43378526772255077 *)
```

The results match exactly to the *R* example in the above link.